# What is ~ for CSS

Tags: css, target

I want to know what the ~ is used for in CSS.

e.g.

```css
#confirmPage:target ~ #navigation #confirm-link,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "general sibling". The selector:

```
a ~ b
```

matches every element matching `b` that comes after an element matching `a`, within the same parent element. For example, take this structure:

```
<p>
    <span>Span 1</span>
    <strong>Strong emphasis</strong>
    <span>Span 2</span>
</p>
```

The selector `p span ~ span` will match the second `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

a ~ b

Selects every 'b' element that are preceded by a 'a' element

Answer (score 0):

The selector «E ~ F» will matches every F element preceded by an E element. So the elements E and F must be on the same tree level, but E must be somewhere before.

Example :

> h1 ~ pre represents a pre element following an h1. It is a correct and
>   valid, but partial, description of:
>
> ## Definition of the function a
>
> Function a(x) has to be
>   applied to all figures in the table.
>
> ```
> function a(x) =
> 12x/13.5
> ```

W3C Selector Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

The tilde(~) is used for the indirect adjacent combinator as part of a selector. Its part of CSS Sibling Combinator. <sup>*[[docs here]](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#sibling-combinators)*</sup>

If you see adjacent selector `a + b` the style will match once the `b` comes right after `a`

But, `a ~ b` generalizes the selection so that `b` can come to any position after a.

```
Example:

h1 ~ pre

represents a pre element following an h1. It is a correct and valid, but partial, description of:

<h1>Definition of the function a</h1>
<p>Function a(x) has to be applied to all figures in the table.</p>
<pre>function a(x) = 12x/13.5</pre>
```